# Cookies are deleted automatically in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I notice that certain cookies saved in my chrome browser are getting deleted automatically without any manual intervention. I have some extensions installed in chrome. I want to know if anybody has faced the same issue. Do certain extension delete cookies on a regular basis? Any information would be helpful

Comment: have you checked that it is not the case that the cookie naturally expired, but some other intervention was involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I know the answer! Google chrome has a cap on the number of cookies it allowed per **domain** . Once the total number of cookies in that domain exceeds that count, it deletes cookies! Verified!

Comment: http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/ is a better source than nothing.
  150 for Firefox, 180 for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to some extension that you have installed. Extensions can have access to clear the cookies.

So, If you have not deleted the cookies manually, then the other extensions installed, are the responsible for clearing the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I have also observed something similar. After updating to Chrome 67 stable about two weeks ago some cookies disappeared. No matter if I set them again, after restarting chrome they are not there. Like the blocking cookie of web statistics/hit counter.

I don't know details, but looks like it may be related to http/https issue, I see in the site info that for some of the http pages background data is not synced in Chrome. 
Or, if the cookie has no expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a setting "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows". Make sure this is disabled. You can find it here: `chrome://settings/cookies`